# Why does using the wildcard signifier for a second "server_name" break my nginx config

Tags: nginx, wildcard, server-name

This config works correctly as expected:

```
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  www.domain1.com domain1.com;

            access_log  /srv/www/domain1.com/logs/access.log;

            location / {
                root   /srv/www/domain1.com/public_html;
                index  index.html index.htm;


    }
    }
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;

            access_log  /srv/www/domain2.com/logs/access.log;

            location / {
                root   /srv/www/domain2.com/public_html;
                index  index.html index.htm;


    }
    }
```

This config displays the content from domain1 when accessing http://domain2.com:

```
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  *.domain1.com;

            access_log  /srv/www/domain1.com/logs/access.log;

            location / {
                root   /srv/www/domain1.com/public_html;
                index  index.html index.htm;


    }
    }
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  *.domain2.com;

            access_log  /srv/www/domain2.com/logs/access.log;

            location / {
                root   /srv/www/domain2.com/public_html;
                index  index.html index.htm;


    }
    }
```

I feel like I'm following the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) correctly in both cases.

What would cause the unexpected behavior using wildcards in example two?

Comment: delete the asterisk if you want your site to be displayed as http://domain2.com. That means you need to have `server_name .domain1.com;` and `server_name .domain2.com;`

Answer (score 0):

`*.domain2.com` doesn't match `domain2.com`. do:

```
server_name  domain2.com *.domain2.com;
```

instead